# Meaning of "Меня слышно?"

Tags: перевод, грамматика, значения

When I play online games I often hear people who have just connected say what sounds like "Меня слышно?"

I think this means "Can you hear me?" because they want to know if their microphone works. However, this seems like incorrect grammar.

Is this a set phrase or am I misinterpreting what they are saying?

Comment: The grammar is correct here.

Comment: You understand the meaning correctly; the literal translation is: **Can I be heard?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a set phrase and - no, you are right in your interpretation.

The structure itself is an ellipsis with an omitted quasi-ergative subject in Dative (elliptical topic):

***(Всем)   (ли)     меня     слышно?***

***All-DAT INTERROG me-ACC heard-NEUT***

The commentary on the topic is an archaic form of participle, which in modern Russian is formally similar to adverbs (cf. ***можно, нужно, важно, видно, слышно*** VS ***осторожно, возможно, рано, поздно,*** etc.).

The other samples of similar structures (I am not sure whether they are  productive or not):

***Можно Вас? / Вам можно / нельзя.***

***Кого (не) нужно (по)звать)?***

***Его / Ему (не) видно.***

***Нас / Нам (не) слышно.***

Some structures, however, are possible only in quasi-ergative forms (unless they contain an elliptical verb).

***Мне рано.***

***Тебе поздно.***

***Каждому понятно.***

***Всем ясно.***

***Им обидно.***

***(Не) каждому дано.***

***Кому-то завидно.***

Comment: That's one of reason why machine translation will fail with russian until they come up with Strong AI.